# virtual machine not having internet connectivity

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am having a VMware Workstation 15 setup.
Following Custom vmnet8 is what I think I have assigned to virtual machine.
vmnet0 I am not using (as per my understanding) but screenshot for information
[image: vmnet0]
vmnet8 is where I expect all connections are going as this I am using for NAT
[image: vmnet8]
[apipa   IP](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/APIPA.html) in virtual machine

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff%12
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.174.62
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

[image: apipa ip to VM]
[image: windows trouble shooter message]

What is the mistake in this configuration.
The Host OS has network connectivity.
***update1***
as per the suggestion in comment I enabled DHCP service in vmnet and connected virtual network adaptor 8 to settings
see this screenshot. So APIPA Ip problem is solved [image: enabled dhcp in virtual network editor]
Now I want to give internet connectivity to Virtual machine that is not happening with above steps. What is the mistake here?

Windows IP Configuration in Virtual Machine

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.152.128
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.152.2
```

IP Configuration of Host OS

Windows IP Configuration

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:fffb%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:fff5%11
                                       192.168.1.1

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:fff4%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.13
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:fff%13
                                       192.168.1.1
```

There are 2 Wifi Cards on this system
Wireless Lan adapter Wifi: Realtek
Wireless Lan Adapter WiFi 2:D Link USB Wifi Adapter

from the guest OS I can ping to 8.8.8.8 
see the screenshot 
[image: guest can ping to 8.8.8.8]
nslookup to www.vmware.com fails
[image: nslookup fails]
This is VMware Workstation 15 Pro
15.1.0 build-13591040
From the host OS I can do not get a ping reply from virtual machine
I do a ping from my host OS to virtual machine (which is running on my laptop)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.152.128

Pinging 192.168.152.128 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.152.128:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

but if I do a ping from my Guest OS to host OS I get a reply.

```
C:\Users\Debian>ping 192.168.1.14

Pinging 192.168.1.14 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

192.168.1.14 is my host OS (IP is given by ADSL router)
192.168.152.128 is IP of my virtual machine this IP is given by VMware DHCP service in vmnet8 in virtual network editor.

Comment: You did not enable DHCP in the VNet.

Comment: Great thanks for pointing that out do I also need to connect a host virtual adaptor to this network option.

Comment: I enabled both the options Connect a host virtual adaptor VMnet8 and Use a Local DHCP service. But Virtual machine did not got internet connectivity.

Comment: here a discussion is related to question  above https://communities.vmware.com/message/2903737#2903737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on a suggestion [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/994722/nslookup-failures-unknown-cant-find-www-vmware-com-query-refused#comment1293939_994722)

it turned out that during a NAT on vmnet8 on home ADSL broadband routers we need to give DNS IP manually so here is a screenshot of how my virtual network editor used to look previously
[image: dns configuration not set on vmnet8]

now based on suggestion I put up my ADSL router IP 192.168.1.1
as DNS IP as in below screenshot
[image: dns added manually]
 nslookup still failed that screenshot after this reset etc
can be seen here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZO2VioostBNYulgn6BT4aqf0C4lQ6yp0/view

after this setting of DNS when I did  nslookup from virtual machine I got an error that reply not found or query could not be answered

however at the time of writing this answer I did nslookup in virtual machine as follows

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Debian>nslookup www.vmware.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.136.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    e751.dscx.akamaiedge.net
Addresses:  2600:1417:2c:194::2ef
          104.114.87.171
Aliases:  www.vmware.com
          www.vmware.com.ds.edgekey.net
```

internet connectivity was there in virtual machine.
[image: internet connected in virtual machine]

as an extra information I am also giving the Network Adapter setting
of VMware Workstation 
[image: network adapter of virtual machine]
now if you see the output of ipconfig on virtual machine it is as below

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.136.133
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.136.2
```

now see the vmnet8 IP in below screenshot 
[image: vmnet8 ip configuration]
vmnet8 ip range is in 192.168.136.x range and IP of my virtual machine which VMware DHCP gave is 192.168.136.133 so obviously virtual machine got IP from vmnet8.
So if you are using VMware behind an ADSL router in broadband  setup
then putting IP of your ADSL router in DNS settings i.e.
virtual network editor-->Vmnet8--->NAT--->DNS Settings
is where you should put it.
I mentioned all this so that if some else gets here in future this should help him.

Also I want to mention that during debugging of all this things had messed up so badly that before proceeding with steps in this answer I had restored defaults from VMware network adapter settings and after that I had applied all the changes as mentioned in screenshot.

Here is a screenshot of ADSL router DNS settings page which is installed and I get internet access from this one, the model is Dlink Product Page: DSL-2750U screenshot of router accessible at 192.168.1.1 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1818cN4eYpT0rr9wu7R0T-pthRxmV1MlV/view